# OV7955 image sensor display green/purple tint

Tags: lens

I have a Omnivision OV7955 color CMOS analog NTSC image sensor. When I connect to the monitor, monitors display green/purple tint. I thought monitors has a problem, but I tried other cameras but monitor works fine. Display images like this:[image]

Obviously, image sensor has a problem. How can I solve this issiue?

Comment: Obviously (for me) lens have a problem (chromatic aberrations)

Comment: OV7955 is connected to the color monitor as you see. Problem is monitor displays clear view, but I can't make it. Only VOP and GND pins connected to the monitors cable. Also, 7955 have external voltage source (5V). Sorry for forget to add more information.

Comment: You do not get it. The image have chromatic aberration. and this is (in 99.9% of the cases) problem of the lens of camera. Check here about more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromatic_aberration

Comment: I don't understand. I tried another lens and the view doesn't change. There is not enough information online about the OV7955 image sensor. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check the cable(s), check near radio emitters. Move a bit the camera, move monitor, also cables.

Comment: Believe me Sir, I have done these thousands times.

Comment: ALso you can try to change (if feasible) the cable which connect camera to monitor, sometime not good contact can have such effect. If this do not work I am short of other ideas :(